# jQuery DatePicker - Change the language to Spanish

Tags: html, jquery, datepicker

I have the following JQuery script:

```
<script>
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd MM y' });
});
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'd MM y' });
});
</script>
```

This script connects with the following html code:

```
<label for="datepicker1">Fecha 1</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker1" class="form-control input-sm">
<label for="datepicker2">Fecha 2</label>
<input type="text" id="datepicker2" class="form-control input-sm">
```

[And this prints the following datepicker in the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRFrF.png)

What I want to do is change the language of the result by choosing the date in the datepicker, that is, instead of indicating **"14 June 2020"**, which index **"14 Junio 2020"** and if possible be **"14 de Junio de 2020"**.

*I hope I have explained myself well, it is the first time that I use this platform.*

Comment: Use English, I don't think that someone will translate your post!

Comment: I have already translated it

Comment: I know it can be hard to come up with the right keywords, but please try searching before posting a new question.  There are many duplicates of this here on SO, searching eg for "jquery datepicker language" will find them.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make use of their *localize* functionality as described in their documentation that you can find [here](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization).

**Example:**

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "es" ] );
    $( "#locale" ).on( "change", function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
        $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
    });
 });
```